# How to configure a server program to autostart at bootup time in SUSE?

Tags: linux, suse, autostart

Are there any good SUSE help sites?t

Answer (score 3):

Server programs are started using scripts linked from `/etc/init.d/rc*.d`. This is the correct way to add another one:

1. Create a shell script called `/etc/init.d/<serverprogram>` with the correct LSB meta information. You can base it on one of the existing scripts, it should be self-explanatory.
2. Then use `insserv` to automatically generate the right symlinks from `/etc/init.d/rc*.d` to it, based on the LSB meta information.